# Quick question about the determinant of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

We know that if $A$ is an orthogonal matrix then $A^{-1}=A^t$ and so $$\det(A)=\pm 1.$$ Put of curiosity, is there a set of conditions that can be added to $A$ such that $\det(A)=1$?

Comment: Yes. E.g. when $A$ is a real orthogonal matrix without any real eigenvalues.

Comment: More generally, a real orthogonal matrix has determinant $1$ if and only if the nullity of $A+I$ is even.