# Question about the determinant on ortogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I know that if $A$ is an ortogonal matrix then $\det(A)=\pm 1$. However, I found this theorem: “If $A$ is an ortogonal matrix then $\det(A)=1$ if and only if $\dim \ker(I+A)$ is an even number.” Here $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

My question is as follows:
1-) Any hints on how to prove this?

2-) If this is true, then does it imply that $\det(A)=-1$ if and only if $\dim \ker(I+A)$ is an odd number?

Thanks :)

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4490407/81360) (and presumably where you found this fact)

Comment: The answer to your second question is yes

Comment: Regarding the proof, it suffices to use the following three facts: the (possibly complex) eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix have absolute value $1$, the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix come in conjugate pairs (which is true for any matrix with real entries), and (as a consequence of the spectral theorem for normal matrices) orthogonal matrices are diagonalizable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of the null space of $I+A$ is the geometric multiplicity $m$ of the eigenvalue $-1$ of $A$ (and zero if $-1$ isn't an eigenvalue).

What are the other possible eigenvalues? Take into account that $A$ is normal, so diagonalizable over the complex numbers and that its complex nonreal eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs.

> The geometric multiplicity is the same as the algebraic multiplicity, because an orthogonal matrix is normal, hence diagonalizable over the complex numbers. The only possible real eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$ and the other eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs of modulus $1$ complex numbers, so the product of such pairs is $1$.

Thus we have $\det A=(-1)^m$.

For the second part, an integer is odd if and only if it is not even.